# Surefire class loaders

Tags: maven, classloader, surefire

In most ClassLoaders

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
classLoader.getResources("");
```

will return an enumeration that includes directories that contain the class files as well as any jars on the class path.  However when executing this code within a maven surefire execution the only items returned are the class and test-class directories.  It seems to make no difference if I use the `useSystemClassLoader` or `useManifestOnlyJar` properties to adjust the class loader.  In addition the class loader (as seen via an attached debugger) appears to have a number of jars attached.

To make things stranger, the debugger shows that the surefire class loader is an instance of the same type as when not running inside surefire.

Does anyone have any pointers for diagnosing the differences or ideas as to how to fix the problem?

Claude

Comment: /*not a maven expert*/ Why do you use thread's context class loader? Does surefire use it? I'm asking because it isn't the class loader that loads classes by default, but often mistaken for it. Also, you're talking about class path - the class loader that has access to the application class path is application class loader (usually same as [system class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader())

Comment: This is in a library that I am working on that finds all the classes on the class path based on specific search criteria (like all the classes with a particular annotation).  My junit contract testing uses it to find the test classes to run.  The problem is that under surefire, if the contract tests are not in the current project it can't find them.  The same code run in Eclipse works fine.

Comment: You didn't answer why do you use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` instead of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` to access class path. In, say, `main()` method of an application these class loaders will be the same, but junit/surefire/anyone starting a new thread may set its context class loader to whatever they want. So it is wrong to expect `getContextClassLoader()` to have access to application class path.

Comment: This all gets rather confusing terminology wise.  The classes I am trying to load may not be in the classpath as defined by CLASSPATH environment variable (or its default).  They are in scope by the class loader used when executing the tests.  In maven this is a jar containing test classes included in the test scope, so it is included in the classloader returned by  <code> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()</code>.   If I get the URLs from the URLClassLoader(s) they do show, up.  So this is my work around.  Not the best solution though.  I would like to see getResources("") work.